# Como recorrer una Lista que contiene otra Lista en Java

Tags: java

Tengo un metodo en java llamado listOperator, que basicamente recive por parametros : **List>**.
La idea es recorrer la lista que tiene dentro a otra lista y sumar todos los numeros que contiene y devolver el valor en total.
Alguna idea de como se recorre dicha lista?.

```java
public static int listOperator(List<List<Integer>> arr) {
      //Code
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un metodo simple es recorrer ambas listas con un for each hasta obtener el valor del integer y relizar la suma:

```
public static int listOperator(List<List<Integer>> arr) {
    int suma = 0;
    for (List<Integer> list : arr) {
        for (Integer integer : list) {
            suma+=integer;
        }
    }
  return suma;
}
```

aqui un snippet con tu ejemplo: https://rextester.com/JBMV53603

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que ya tienes llena tu lista, lo que tienes que hacer, es lo siguiente:

```
for(int i=0; i<arr.size(); i++){
    int suma = 0;
    for(int c=0; c<arr.get(i).size(); c++){
        suma += arr.get(i).get(c);
    }
    System.out.println(suma);
}
```

Esto te imprimirá la suma de cada uno de los elementos de las sublistas, si requieres sumar las sublistas, entre sí... Solamente inicializa la variable fuera del ciclo.